# why doesn't this div get the background?

Tags: html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/74MvW/) there is the whole example of my divs.

Why doesn't `footer` get the background color from the parent (`container`)?

Comment: Another thing you should never have text directly in a div. You should always put a "p" tag around your text.

Comment: @Raffael: Why do you think that? If you put it into a <p> tag then you'll have more DOM elements generated and gain nothing. If you leave it as simple text then it'll simply be a text node in the DOM. <p> also has some nastly default styling which you have to get rid almost always ...

Comment: @Raffael Luthiger : I don't agree with that opinion. Sorry

Comment: I also disagree on adding another element without having a parent with a specific purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `float` an element, this is like it was disconnected from the parent. So, `inherit` values cannot be inherited. Also, the parent stops expanding to the children heights. Remove the `float` and you can see it working.

But if you really need the `float`, you need to put `background-color` on `footer`.

Remember that you can put another `<div style="clear: both"></div>` after `footer` like showed on another answer, but it is just a trick to that the parent can follow the child height.

Comment: Yes, floated elements do not contribute to the parents layout. In this case the `container` has nothing contributing to its height, thus it remains `height = 0`

Comment: I am with Dan Manastireanu: The height of the parent div is still zero, which can create unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

You have to clear the floating div: http://jsfiddle.net/74MvW/14/

Comment: Take care about using `<div />` without selfclosing tag. Some browsers don't like it to block elements.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get the bg color, because the "container" div has the background, but the "footer" div is floating to left, which means that it doesn't affect the "container" div's height.

You have to either get rid of the float or simply add a clearer div after the footer div like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="footer">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;float:none;"><!-- Clearer --></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, the problem is the `float` value.  The nicest way to get around this is to set the `.footer` div to "inherit" the parent's background:

```
.footer {width:910px; height:150px; float:left; background: inherit}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74MvW/13/).

Some CSS properties are inherited by default (e.g. `font-family`); others have default properties.  In the case of `background-color`, the default is `transparent`.  If you want the property to be inherited, you have to say so explicitly.

Comment: Although i like the inherit solution, there is a problem. The .container div has still a height of 0px because of the single float content without the presence of clearing elements. This shouldn't be the case. If .container would have a border, it wouldn't be wrapped correctly around the .footer, for example.

Comment: @Alp True.  I was aiming for "interesting alternative point" rather than "conclusive answer for all ever and ever amen" with this answer ;-)